# Android slow down TranslateAnimation over time

Tags: android, android-animation

I wanted to make my own animations for fragment transitions. I want it to come in from the bottom fast and then slow down as it reaches its position. I have done something similar in the past but i don't have the code anymore and i can't reproduce it either :/ I remember it had something to do with the interpolator.

This is my current animation set

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="200">
  <translate
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the `interpolator` to your `<set>` like this:

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
```

Source: [Animation resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource)